# What can a `RecordBatch` do that a `StructArray` cannot?

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

Among the different types of arrays that exist in Arrow, one of them is the `StructArray`. When converted to a pandas structure using PyArrow, it returns a `pd.Series` with a number of rows, each of them containing a dictionary:

```
>>> pa.array([{'x': 1, 'y': True}, {'z': 3.4, 'x': 4}]).to_pandas()
0    {'x': 1.0, 'y': True, 'z': None}
1     {'x': 4.5, 'y': None, 'z': 3.4}
dtype: object
```

On the other hand, a `RecordBatch` advertises itself as "a collection of equal-length array instances":

```
>>> pa.RecordBatch.from_pylist([{'x': 1, 'y': True, 'z': None}, {'z': 3.4, 'x': 4.5}]).to_pandas()
     x     y    z
0  1.0  True  NaN
1  4.5  None  3.4
```

However, even if one takes the form of a `pd.Series` and the other a `pd.DataFrame`, it seems to me that, essentially, they both contain the same information. One is an array, the other is a collection of arrays.

Therefore, what can a `RecordBatch` do that a `StructArray` cannot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're different abstractions. A StructArray is an Array with an associated type; it's a nested array. A RecordBatch is a…RecordBatch and contains a schema; abstractly, it's a 2D chunk of data where each column is contiguous in memory.

They intentionally have similar interfaces because they "look similar" to each other, but for instance, a StructArray can't be written to a file by itself; it would need to be wrapped and converted into a RecordBatch.

Also, StructArray (as an Array) has a top-level validity bitmap (i.e. each of its child arrays has their own validity information, and so does the StructArray itself). But a RecordBatch doesn't have its own validity bitmap.

Comment: Thanks @li.davidm. From your first paragraph, I understand that a `StructArray` is fully contiguous, whereas a `RecordBatch` has its arrays (columns) contiguous in memory, but it doesn't need to be fully contiguous itself?

Comment: And about your second paragraph, you illustrate what I think it's a key point: that "The primitive unit of serialized data in the columnar format is the “record batch”" https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Columnar.html#serialization-and-interprocess-communication-ipc I overlooked this initially

Comment: Both StructArray and RecordBatch are fully contiguous, in the sense that the child arrays of a StructArray and the columns of a RecordBatch (which are also arrays!) are contiguous in memory.

Comment: Ah yes, I explained myself poorly. What I meant is that child array A and child array B are both contiguous, but they don't have to be adjacent to one another. Same goes with the columns of the RecordBatch, I suppose.

Comment: Ah - yes, you are correct. Individual arrays are contiguous (or rather, individual buffers in arrays), but the arrays themselves are almost certainly disjoint.